Что делать если шапка сайта закрывает основной текст контейнера?
У меня есть сайт с шапкой со значением Абсолют. При прокрутке она фиксируется, но когда нажимаешь на кнопку в шапке, происходит скролл при этом шапка закрывает чать контента.
ссылка на сайт: https://asnekom.github.io/MY_Works/
Уточняю при нажатии кнопки история и работы шапка закрывает половину слова.
Нашел ответ в этом видео:https://youtube.com/shorts/SwVDBg479TI?si=7Z6n_yVF3uRikCSG

Спрашиваете: что делать? Отвечаю: исправлять, скорее всего в стилях и смотреть что делается по нажатию на кнопку. Без вашего HTML, css и кнопки более подробно сказать нельзя

Именно какая кнопка? Я смотрю и все норм

добавьте блокам к которым скроллите паддинг сверху побольше - как раз на высоту навигации. А иначе - смириться, если js не знаете - убрать из css плавный скролл и использовать window.scroll - в нем сдвигать top повыше, чтобы не перекрывал блок.

Измени стили так .header__nav {     background: var(--dark);     /* padding: 23px 0; */     height: 10vh;     line-height: 10vh;     position: fixed;     width: 100%;     /* top: 0; */     /* left: 0; */     z-index: 9999999999; }

Возможное решение использовать vh или % в стиле и задать основному контейнеру высоту где вы вычитиваете высоту навбара а самому навбару тоже задать относительную высоту. Тогда все будет ОК

можно поконкретнее
